# How do I pass a cursor value when calling a stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

This is only my second time diagnosing a PL/SQL procedure.  I need to test the code in the stored procedure, and I'm trying to call it in SQL Developer.  I have run the error details report, and the code has no obvious bugs in it.

So now I am trying to run it through a test window so I can see if the output is correct.  However I can't seem to get the right argument for the 3 parameter.  Here are the parameters in the the procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ADVANCE.WW_DEATHDATE_REPORT(begindate varchar2, enddatevarchar2, RC1 IN OUT du_refCUR_PKG.RC) AS
```

Here is the Code I am trying to use to call the procedure.  What do I need to do to get it to run correct?  I keep getting error messages saying I'm using a wrong value in the parameter.

```
BEGIN
ADVANCE.WW_DEATHDATE_REPORT('20100101','20150101',du_refcur_pkg);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, one way is like the below,

```
DECLARE 
du_refcur_pkg SYS_REFCURSOR; 
BEGIN 
OPEN du_refcur_pkg FOR SELECT ... ; 

ADVANCE.WW_DEATHDATE_REPORT('20100101','20150101',du_refcur_pkg);
END;
```

Another way would be,

```
BEGIN 
ADVANCE.WW_DEATHDATE_REPORT( '20100101','20150101', CURSOR (SELECT ... ) ); 
END;
```